# Auto-Comment for Facebook Group Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, facebook-group, autocommenting

I've posted a pre-launch announcement for a new product in an active group and I got 2500+ comments from people who want to get the product. I want to respond to each single comment with the details when I will launch it into the market.  If there any method, script, or a free software to do that?

---

Edit: I wonder could it be done by a script using Greasemonkey? addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey

Comment: I got what I'm looking for.. with lots of functionalities. https://github.com/ZiaUrR3hman/FacebookAutoLikeProfessional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to comment in groups anymore:

> 90-day Deprecations in Graph API v2.10
>
> POST and DELETE operations for the /{comment-id} node and the
>   /{object-id}/comments edge will now be restricted to Pages with valid
>   page access tokens.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_10

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wonder could it be done by a script using Greasemonkey? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Comment: scraping is not allowed, so no, there is no way at all. and after all, you would want to autocomment to 2500+ entries, that would be the motherload of spam ;)